# How to append a line using sed in Linux yaml file after matching exact string

Tags: linux, sed, command-line

I am not able to find a way to append a line in yaml file after exact match of string but ignoring similar string having other values in it in a line. There are some example but that is not my case. I have a yaml file and I am automating its configuration instead of adding values manually by going to line number, I am trying to find out a string and then after that, I am adding the value using sed command.

Here is the example

**My current file a.yaml**

```
rules:
  - name: Block PH by GeoIP country
    script: ./rules/Block PH by GeoIP country.js
    stage: login_success
    enabled: false
........
........
........
- name: Preview-1 API (Test Application)
  allowed_clients: []
  app_type: non_interactive
  callbacks: []                             <<<<< -------  see string "callbacks:" with brackets
  client_aliases: []
........
........
........
  allowed_logout_urls:
    - 'http://local.example.com:/login'
  allowed_origins: []
  callbacks:                           <<<<< -------  see string "callbacks:" where I want to append
    - 'http://local.example.com:/callback'
```

**Command**

```
sed -i "/callbacks:/a \ \ \ \ \ \ - 'https://d1.example.com/callback'" > a.yaml
```

**Results of the Command**

```
My Updated File a.yaml

rules:
  - name: Block PH by GeoIP country
    script: ./rules/Block PH by GeoIP country.js
    stage: login_success
    enabled: false
........
........
........
- name: Preview-1 API (Test Application)
  allowed_clients: []
  app_type: non_interactive
  callbacks: []                             
    - 'https://d1.example.com/callback'   <<<<< -------  see problem here
  client_aliases: []
........
........
........
  allowed_logout_urls:
    - 'http://local.example.com:/login'
  allowed_origins: []
  callbacks:                           
    - 'https://d1.example.com/callback'          <<<<< -------  I appended
    - 'http://local.example.com:/callback'
```

**What I want**

```
    rules:
  - name: Block PH by GeoIP country
    script: ./rules/Block PH by GeoIP country.js
    stage: login_success
    enabled: false
........
........
........
- name: Preview-1 API (Test Application)
  allowed_clients: []
  app_type: non_interactive
  callbacks: []                                <<<<< -------  I don't want to append here
  client_aliases: []
........
........
........
  allowed_logout_urls:
    - 'http://local.example.com:/login'
  allowed_origins: []
  callbacks:                           
    - 'https://d1.example.com/callback'          <<<<< -------  I want my addition only after this
    - 'http://local.example.com:/callback'
```

I don't want to append my line after every matching string, in my above example there are 2 lines having 2 values callbacks: [] and callbacks: so I am trying to append after callbacks: only.

**Scenario**

I wanted to use sed command in my bash script file where I will pass variable value for this line like this - 'https://$1.example.com/callback' and command would be like this

```
sed -i "/callbacks:/a \ \ \ \ \ \ - 'https://$1.example.com/callback'" > a.yaml
```

In this way I can reuse this script by passing any value and append line which will look as below

```
  callbacks:               
    - 'https://z.example.com/callback'
    - 'https://b.example.com/callback'
    - 'https://d1.example.com/callback'
    - 'http://local.example.com:/callback'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$` to match the end of the line:

```
sed -i "/callbacks:$/a\
\    - 'https://d1.example.com/callback'" a.yaml
```

Comment: How to add space? as you know its yaml file so the string should be properly placed.
Right now, it requires 2 spaces.

Comment: Which spaces do you mean? Before "callback" or before the inserted string? The command worked for me for the given example.

Comment: The command worked for me as well, I am talking about the line we added, before the line there should be 2 more spaces.

Comment: It doesn't work if you add two more spaces after ```\```?

Comment: It gives syntax error and code do not execute. Its yaml syntax and it requires values on exact and same place as per requirement  in whole file.

Comment: No I tried, it didn't worked by addiing "\"

Comment: I modified my answer, please try again.